# Apollo and type-graphql can't find input mutation/query

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo, typegraphql

I'm trying to pass an input to my graphql query and my resolver can't find the input

I have my docker container set to log info and I can see the input is being passed, the log that gets posted looks like this:

```
{ getAllPayments(input: {processed: true}) { id processed } }
```

But when I console log `input` it contains my entity manager data:

```
<ref *3> EntityManager {
  repositories: [],
  plainObjectToEntityTransformer: PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer {},
  connection: <ref *1> Connection {
    migrations: [...],
    subscribers: [],
    entityMetadatas: [
      [EntityMetadata],
      [EntityMetadata],
      [EntityMetadata],
      [EntityMetadata]
    ],
    name: 'default',
    options: {...},
    logger: AdvancedConsoleLogger { options: undefined },
    driver: PostgresDriver {...},
    manager: EntityManager {
      repositories: [],
      plainObjectToEntityTransformer: PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer {},
      connection: [Circular *1]
    },
    namingStrategy: DefaultNamingStrategy {
      nestedSetColumnNames: [Object],
      materializedPathColumnName: 'mpath'
    },
    metadataTableName: 'typeorm_metadata',
    queryResultCache: undefined,
    relationLoader: RelationLoader { connection: [Circular *1] },
    isConnected: true
  },
  queryRunner: <ref *2> PostgresQueryRunner {
    isReleased: false,
    isTransactionActive: true,
    data: {},
    loadedTables: [],
    loadedViews: [],
    sqlMemoryMode: false,
    sqlInMemory: SqlInMemory { upQueries: [], downQueries: [] },
    transactionDepth: 1,
    cachedTablePaths: {},
    driver: PostgresDriver {...},
    connection: <ref *1> Connection {...},
    mode: 'master',
    broadcaster: Broadcaster { queryRunner: [Circular *2] },
    manager: [Circular *3],
    databaseConnectionPromise: Promise { [Client] },
    databaseConnection: Client {...}
    },
    releaseCallback: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
}
```

I replaced some objects with `{...}`*

My resolver looks like this:

```
  @Transaction()
  @Query(() => [Payment], { nullable: false })
  async getAllPayments(
    @Arg('input', { nullable: true }) input?: GetPaymentsInput
  ): Promise<Payment[]> {
    if (!input?.processed) {
      throw new ApolloError('no input passed');
    }

    return getCustomRepository(PaymentRepository).getAll({
      processed: input?.processed,
      paymentProvider: input?.paymentProvider,
      paymentType: input.paymentType,
    });
  }
```

And my `GetPaymentsInput` type looks like this:

```
@InputType({
  description: 'Input type for getting payments.',
})
export class GetPaymentsInput {
  @Field(() => Boolean, {
    nullable: true,
    description: 'Whether or not the payment is processed.',
  })
  processed?: boolean;
...
}
```

Comment: Strange... can you share the code?

Comment: @CarloCorradini which code exactly are you looking for? It's a private repo so I can't share the entire thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any problem with your code :/